# Vercel deploy can't detect properties on interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel, zod

I was setting up my monorepo on Vercel to deploy a Next.js project which is included in the monorepo (rest of projects in the repo are Express.js microservices). The Next.js project imports several types generated by the Express.js projects - production build works fine on my local PC with no type errors, but when deploying to Vercel I get compile errors saying "Type error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'WorkerFullInformation'" as one example.

My folder system looks like this:

```
monorepo:
| /nextjs-app
  | /src
    | /pages
      | /dashboard
        | installers.tsx
| /microservice-1
  | /src
    | /types
      | /workers
        | WorkerFullInformation.ts
...
```

It seems like Vercel is able to import this, because the compile error is complaining about properties not existing on this type:

[image: Picture of Vercel error]

Here is a snippet of my editor, where it is clear that 'id' is a defined property on this object:
[image: The exported interface in WorkerFullInformation.ts]

[image: WorkerModel type]

This setup works perfectly on my local environment with both npm run dev and npm run build -- production, so perhaps I am missing something in my Vercel project configuration? Would be happy if anyone has any input on this! ;)